# Why is all the text in my html div chaning color when using Ajax $().css

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a script retrieving 4 attributes from a database table using Ajax and PHP. One of the attributes is the font color for the HTML output. The attribute is put into a variable called 'type'. I am trying to  assign  the  font color to a specific row in the HTML output, but the  entire HTML output changes font color and not only the one specific row. I am fairly new to this, so any help is appreciated.

HTML div

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Here is my function

```
function getEvent()
  {    
  console.log("function call");   
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get_events.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success:     function(rows)
  {
    for (var i in rows)
    {
      var row = rows[i];

      var id = row[0];
      var type = row[1];
      var vname = row[2];
      var time = row[3];

        $('#output').css('color', type).prepend("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> event: </b>"+vname+"<b> time: </b>"+time+"</br>")
        type='black';
    }
  }
});
  };
```

Comment: $('#output') is targeting a fixed DOM element (by id), but you are doing this in a loop, so you are effectively changing the 'color' of whatever the same object (whatever element has id='output') over and over for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping `prepand` and `css` with minor selector update upon setting font color shall fix issue, try to replace line `$('#output').css...` with lines below:

```
$('#output').prepend("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> event: </b>"+vname+"<b> time: </b>"+time+"</br>");
$('#output b:first-child').css('color', type)
```

Comment: @user2120143 you are welcome, could you mark answer as accepted to keep you question on SO ... ?